# How to get the difference of created_at and updated_at in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I've researched about on internet but what I found is only getting the past time `(e.g. 4mins ago)`, **What I want** is to get the difference from `created_at` and `updated_at` in my database and like so, `3days 3hrs 23mins 30sec` **and** if there's no `mins` or `hrs`, just output the `3days 3hrs 30sec` or `3days 23mins 30sec`.

**What I have:**

*view*

```
@foreach($submits as $submit)
   {{ $submit->pivot->created_at }} // to get the created_at
   {{ $submit->pivot->updated_at }} // to get the updated_at
@endforeach
```

Comment: Have you read the Carbon documentation? It should contain everything you ask for. http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Yes, maybe I can use this `CarbonInterval::create(2, 0, 5, 1, 1, 2, 7);`, but how can I compare the two values?

Comment: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find days, hours, minutes and seconds by using this function.

```
public function getDifference($created_at, $updated_at) {
    $days = $created_at->diffInDays($updated_at);
    $hours = $created_at->diffInHours($updated_at->subDays($days));
    $minutes = $created_at->diffInMinutes($updated_at->subHours($hours));
    $seconds = $created_at->diffInSeconds($updated_at->subMinutes($minutes));
    return CarbonInterval::days($days)->hours($hours)->minutes($minutes)->seconds($seconds)->forHumans();
}
```

Output

```
3 days 3 hours 23 minutes 30 seconds
```

Comment: I got too much `seconds`, **1 hour 21 minutes 3547 seconds** which should be converted

Comment: I am using the same. But never get any issue.

Comment: Try this `created: 2017-10-03 11:07:18`, `updated: 2017-10-03 12:29:11`

Comment: Yes.. there is an issue in the function. I have updated my answer. Thank you for the finding.. :)

Comment: There's still an issue, I'm getting `1 hour 21 minutes 53 seconds` instead of `1 hour 22 minutes 07 seconds`